# HOOKPROC callback doesn't get called by the hook - C#

Tags: c#, c++, interop, hook

I'm trying to set a low-level keyboard hook. I have DLL with the following code:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace InputListener;

public class LowLevelKeyboardHook : IDisposable
{
    const int GLOBAL_HOOK = 0;

    readonly HOOKPROC _callback;
    readonly IntPtr _hHook;

    public IntPtr Handle => _hHook;

    public LowLevelKeyboardHook(HOOKPROC hookCallback, bool throwOnFail = false)
    {
        _callback = hookCallback;
        IntPtr hHookProcModule;
        using (var currentModule = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule)
            hHookProcModule = GetModuleHandle(currentModule);
        
        _hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, hHookProcModule, GLOBAL_HOOK);
        var errorCode = GetLastError();

        if (throwOnFail && hHookProcModule == IntPtr.Zero) throw new DllNotFoundException("The module where the callback defined could not be retrieved.");
        if (throwOnFail && Handle == default) throw new Exception("The hook could not be set.");
    }

    static IntPtr GetModuleHandle(ProcessModule? module)
    {
        return GetModuleHandle(module?.ModuleName!); ;
    }

    IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0) _callback(nCode, wParam, lParam);
        return CallNextHookEx(Handle, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    extern static IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
    extern static int GetLastError();

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    extern static IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int hookType, HOOKPROC lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    extern static bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 0xD;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(Handle);
    }
}

public delegate IntPtr HOOKPROC(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

After including this DLL to a console application and running the following code, `LowLevelKeyboardProc` never gets called but `errorCode` holds 0 and all handles are returned:

```
Task.Run(() => {
    var hook = new LowLevelKeyboardHook(TestProc);
    while (true) ;
});
while (true) ;

IntPtr TestProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Works");
    return default;
}
```

Please, help me with this one. I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out the reason why the callback doesn't get called. I peeked into the code of other people and they do virtually the same things I do but my code doesn't seem to work. Currently, I think that the issue might well be in the loop that I use for testing the hook. When I run the program.

Comment: Too many mistakes, use a [library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MouseKeyHook/).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a couple of redditors I found out that the hook seems not to work because there is no message loop in console applications.

> This hook is called in the context of the thread that installed it. The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook. Therefore, the thread that installed the hook must have a message loop.